# How to "build" the sigma-algebra of cylinders

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Consider $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^T$ and the class of all cylinders, i.e. $$\mathcal{C} = C_{t_1, ..., t_n}(A) : n\geq 1, t_1, ..., t_n \in T, A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R^n}) \subset \mathbb{R}^T$$
I have proved that this is an algebra. In order to show that it is not a $\sigma$-algebra, I have showed with a counterexample that it is not closed under countable intersections as follows.
Consider $$K = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} C_{t_1, ..., t_n} (0,1)^n$$ with $T=[0, \infty)$ and $t_1 < t_2 < ...$. Then $$ K = \lbrace \omega = \omega(t): \omega(t_i) \in (0,1) \; \forall i \rbrace$$ It is a countable intersection of elements of $\mathcal{C}$, but it is not a cylinder since it imposes restrictions on an infinite number of coordinates.

However, I was wondering if it was possible to "build" a $\sigma$-algebra adding to $\mathcal{C}$ also the cylinders with infinite conditions in order to solve the problem I just described. Conversely, is there a counterexample that proves that also this "augmented" version of $\mathcal{C}$ is still not a $\sigma$-algebra?

Thank you in advance